# How to apply "in list" operator with Nest (C#) library using the elastic search?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co) server that I want to query. I want to replicate the behavior of `in` operator in a SQL server using the [NEST](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) library.

Here is a short version of the `Product` class which is what I am using to search where the `Type` field is in `request.Types`

```
public class Product
{
    [Text(Name = "types")]
    public string[] Types { get; set; }

    [Text(Name = "price")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Here is my query request using the Nest library

```
var properties = await client.SearchAsync<Product>(x =>
{
    x = x.Query(q =>
    {
        if (request.MinPrice.HasValue || request.MaxPrice.HasValue)
        {
            q.Range(r =>
           {
               if (request.MinPrice.HasValue)
               {
                   r = r.Field(x => x.Price).GreaterThanOrEquals((double)request.MinPrice.Value);
               }

               if (request.MaxPrice.HasValue)
               {
                   r = r.Field(x => x.Price).LessThanOrEquals((double)request.MaxPrice.Value);
               }
               return r;
           });
        }

        if (request.Types != null && request.Types.Length > 0)
        {
            
            // Here I need to query the Type field where field in request.Types
        }

        return q;
    });

    return x;
});
```

As you can see in the comment above, I want to add the "in clause" only when the `request.Types` has value and the server has at least one matching type.

How can I add `in clause` condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two possible interpretations of the requirement:

1. query documents that have `Types` that intersect with `request.Types`

   A [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) can achieve this. Typically, a terms query targets a field mapped as a `keyword` type, but `Product.Types` is mapped as a `text` type. You may want to consider changing the mapping to map as `keyword`, or map it as both `text` and `keyword` with a multi-field.

   With `Product.Types` mapped as a `keyword` type, the query would be

   ```cs
   q.Terms(t => t
       .Field(f => f.Types)
       .Terms(request.Types)
   );
   ```
2. query documents that have all the exact `Types` specified in `request.Types`

   A [terms set query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html) can achieve this. As before, the `Types` field should be mapped as a `keyword`, then the query would be

   ```cs
   q.TermsSet(t => t
       .Field(f => f.Types)
       .Terms(request.Types)
       .MinimumShouldMatchScript(s => s
          .Source("params.request_types_len")
          .Params(d => d
              .Add("request_types_len", request.Types.Length)
          )
       )
   );
   ```

Comment: the field `type` is of type `keyword` on the server. The first code you provided does not work as the method `Values()` is not found. Here is the error in VS,  `TermsQueryDescripter<Product> does not contain a definition for `Values` and no accessible extenation method `Values` accepting a first argument....`

Comment: sorry, should've been `Terms()` - amended